# Shell script in cron.daily does not work

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I want to backup my database daily automatically, so I made a shell script, and then put it in `cron.daily` folder in Ubuntu 12.

The script is not complicated,

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=/db_backups/$DIR
mkdir $DEST
mongodump -d myapp -o $DEST
```

this script works well when I run manually like `./automongobackup.sh` then It make a backup file in proper location. So I expected If I put it in `cron.daily`, the backup database will generated automatically, But I checked backup folder today the folder was empty and realize something wrong.

Should I set a another option? The `chmod` is 755. I attached some screenshots, The first one is my `ls-l` in `cron.daily` and second is script. Any missing I did?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably you need to set the full PATH to mongodump. Have you checked your syslog for daily crontab log entries? What does it tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your script to 'automongobackup' rather than 'automongobackup.sh' as `run-parts` which handles the crons in cron.daily, and cron.hourly etc doesn't like fullstops/periods in the filename.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/611336/why-putting-a-script-in-etc-cron-hourly-is-not-working